# iPad Air Freezing During Debugging

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

Every consecutive time I run the debug version of an app on an iPad Air, it freezes on the app's splash screen and the device becomes unresponsive. If I try to sleep during this, I'm unable to wake it. At one point my log mentioned something about an error trying to exit process -1, but I haven't been able to replicate it successive times. If xcode attempts to run another app during this state, it states

"error: failure to launch '/private/var/mobile/Applications/25084256-F580-4947-8642-BF0D0A7EC6BE/AppInQuestion.app' -- Busy."

Siri was responsive initially, but successive requests ended up being met with something along the lines of "Something is wrong, and I am unable to answer your question at this time." Asking Siri to shut down and getting confirmation from her did not actually shut the device down.

I was able to recover the device by holding down the sleep/wake and home buttons until the apple logo appeared.

I'm using xcode 5. After I try running the app the second time, xcode launches the app to the splash screen, but displays no errors and looks as if the app never launched.

Does anybody know of a better way to handle this other than uninstalling every time? Or why it's happening?

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem with the iPhone 5S. The app launches the first time then successive launches cause Springboard to mess up and the error message comes up. The background on the phone is black and doesn't respond to anything.

Comment: Have nearly the same trouble with iPhone 4S - once in a while it just freezes my device completely so I need a hard reset. Damn Xcode 5.

Comment: You should check the Applications > Utilities > Console application for more clues. Then update your question with any relevant info.

Comment: It's a common problem and it has nothing to do with devices (I got the same problem with both iPad Mini and iPhone5s), it's several bugs both in LLDB debugger and Xcode5. Hopefully, new update will fix this.

Comment: I didn't get a chance to try it out with the Console app just yet (pretty popular with the other devs), but I'll give that a shot along with trying out the Xcode 5.0.2 and report back anything new as soon as I can. With any luck it'll be fixed with the next xcode patch.

Comment: Still happens to me with Xcode 5.0.2

Comment: Had the same issue on my iPhone 5 with XCode 5.0.2 public release; Pressing Home & Sleep/Wake buttons together for about 10 seconds rebooted the phone.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue and I can get it works to use the new Xcode (5.0.2 GM seed) from developer website to run the testing on iPad Air.

Comment: Release notes for 5.0.2 state that it fixes this issue.